# Need to find adapter for laptop ATAPi/IDE to SATA

Tags: sata, adapter, blu-ray

I need to integrate a **9.5 or 12.7 mm laptop optical BluRay drive** into a small form factor case that only accepts a **slot in** drive. I have the slot in drive but it some small/slim **ATAPI/IDE**.

The problem I am facing is that the mini-ITX main board does not have IDE and the laptop BluRay drive is IDE.

[image: Interface reference photo]

What adapter that will allow me to interface this drive to my main board?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a motherboard bridge adapter such as the following IDE to SATA Adapter:

[image: IDE to SATA Adapter]

**References**

- [3.5" HDD IDE/PATA to SATA Converter Add On Card Adapte for IDE 40-pin hard drive disk,DVD Burner to SATA 7pin Motherboard - Newegg.com](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIACJF54C2846&Description=ide%20to%20sata%20bridge&cm_re=ide_to_sata_bridge-_-9SIACJF54C2846-_-Product)
- [File:IDE-SATA ADAPTER.jpg - Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IDE-SATA_ADAPTER.jpg)